# Magento loadByAttribute() work strange

Tags: magento-1.9

When I try to load product by string:

`$P->loadByAttribute('my_attr', '123');` 
it's work. When I try the same by variable: 
`$P->loadByAttribute('my_attr', $v);` 
where $v is a string variable containing '123' it don't. Why?

Comment: Have you tried $P->loadByAttribute('my_attr', ''.$v.'');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable with **string"". i.e.,

```
   $P->loadByAttribute('my_attr', (string)$v); .
```

Or the attribute is a integer value use `(int)`.